# Android RecyclerViewAdapter overwrites list data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Could anyone explain me, why does the List connectionsCategories is being owerwritten in this part of code? I am trying to filter data inside Filter's performFiltering method placed inside RecyclerView. As I've noticed the list takes new values in this line:                             connectionsCategoryModelCopy.setValues(filteredConnectionsModels);

```
String charString = charSequence.toString();
            filteredConnectionsCategories.clear();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                filteredConnectionsCategories.addAll(connectionsCategories);
            } else {
                List<ConnectionsCategoryModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (ConnectionsCategoryModel connectionsCategoryModel : connectionsCategories) {
                    ConnectionsCategoryModel connectionsCategoryModelCopy = connectionsCategoryModel;
                    List<ConnectionsModel> connectionsModels = connectionsCategoryModelCopy.getValues();
                    List<ConnectionsModel> filteredConnectionsModels = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (ConnectionsModel connectionsModel : connectionsModels) {
                        if (connectionsModel.getName().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "").contains(charString.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""))) {
                            filteredConnectionsModels.add(connectionsModel);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!filteredConnectionsModels.isEmpty()) {
                        connectionsCategoryModelCopy.setValues(filteredConnectionsModels);
                        filteredList.add(connectionsCategoryModelCopy);
                    }
                }
                filteredConnectionsCategories = filteredList;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ConnectionsCategoryModel connectionsCategoryModelCopy = connectionsCategoryModel;
```

This line here is your issue. You are making a "shallow copy" here. When you get this list:

```
  List<ConnectionsModel> connectionsModels = connectionsCategoryModelCopy.getValues();
```

you need to do a "deep copy" of each element before you do your replace call.